# Алгоритм поиска всех подмножеств множества

Tags: python

Данный алгоритм должен виводить все подмножества заданного множества(в виде списка):

```
new_array=[1,2,3,4]
power_set=[[]]
for x in new_array:
    new_set=power_set
    for i in range(len(new_set)):
        new_set[i].append(x)
    power_set.extend(new_set)
print(power_set)
```

Но вместо задачи он выводит кучу всяких непонятных подмножеств.
Можете объяснить где ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

```
new_array=[1,2,3,4]
power_set=[[]]
for x in new_array:
    print(power_set)
    for i in range(len(power_set)):
        tmp_list = power_set[i].copy()
        tmp_list.append(x)
        power_set.append(tmp_list)
print(power_set)
```

Например так. Ваша ошибка - вы не делаете копию списка, вы работаете с самим списком по другой ссылке.

Comment: Я добавил в своем коде .copy(),но оно все равно не работает.В консоли оно выдает следуйщие результаты: видно,что временный список,есть таким каким он должен быть,но после слития с главным,в  главном пустой список меняется на той которым есть временным,тоесть не действует копия списка,почему?

Comment: @VitalykChernysh копировать надо 2 раза. Один раз весь список в новый, второй в цикле вложенные списки.